# need to return an array of records but javascript returns object object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, records

I'm really stuck on the last few functions on my coursework. More specifically, the following: in this function I am trying to count how many times a pattern occurs in the `content` field of an array of records. I then want to return a new array with the corresponding `url` and `score` (if the score is greater than 0). The code is longer than it needs to be because I tried breaking each bit down as much as I could to make it as basic as it can be, but I still can't see where I've gone wrong.

```
function urlScores(web, pattern){
  var records = {};  
  var results = [];  
  var n = 0;  
  for(var i = 0; i < web.length; i++){  
    n = score(web[i].content, pattern);  
    if(n != 0){  
      records.url = web[i].url;  
      records.score = n;  
      results[results.length] = {url: records.url, score: records.score};  
    }  
  }  
  return(results);  
}  

 var web = [ {url : "www.southampton.ac.uk",  content : "Southampton University offers degree programmes and world class research." } , {url : "www.xyz.ac.uk",  content : "An alternative University" } , {url : "www",  content : "Yet another University" } ];  

 alert(urlScores(web, 'uni'));
```

this outputs [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] but it should output

```
[{url: "www.southampton.ac.uk", score: 1}, {url: "www.xyz.ac.uk", score: 1}, {url: "www", score: 1}]
```

I understand how returning an object does not return its value but its position (or something similar) but I cannot figure out how to get the individual values in each record to display neatly with its field name in an array.

Any help is appreciated, sorry if my code is of poor quality, I'm fairly new to JavaScript.

this is not a duplicate due to the fact we are not allowed to use any libraries or methods we have not yet learnt. please only answer with the most basic Javascript techniques if at all possible.

Comment: your code appears to be correct, your `alert` is flawed - it casts the array to a string. Use `alert(JSON.stringify(…))` or `console.log(…)` instead

Comment: `window.alert` casts the value to a string `String({}) -> "[object Object]"` You can use `console.log(data)` to debug your code / data

Comment: sorry i should've mentioned that our course criteria is that we are not allowed to use any method we have not yet learnt. we haven't covered either of those yet :( we have only done very basic javascript and are not allowed the use of libraries. this probably makes it much harder than necessary...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In the future, don't use `>` to format your code; that's for block *text* quotes, not code blocks. You can create a code block with four spaces at the beginning of the line. You may be interested in [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: @air6199 are you just alerting for testing purposes or is it a requirement of your coursework to alert that string? `JSON.stringify` and `console.log` are standard methods in javascript—not part of a library.

Comment: @apsillers thank you! i read a page earlier that said to indent 4 times but i've always known that as pressing tab 4 times and that just skipped to the next text box! thanks for clarifying that

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the assignment is to write a function that returns an array of objects, not to write a function that displays this result as a string nicely.

Comment: @DavidSherret the requirement is to return the value instead of alerting it but for testing purposes i had alerted it. either way, unfortunately we have not covered either of those methods yet therefore we cannot use them :(

Comment: If you really want to reimplement the wheel, er, `JSON.stringify`, you need to state in your question *which methods and basics you already have learnt*.

Comment: @air6199 just do what Bergi suggested and change your line from `alert(urlScores(web, 'uni'));` to `alert(JSON.stringify(urlScores(web, 'uni')));`. Don't be afraid to use something you haven't learned if you're not going to submit it to the instructor.

Comment: @Bergi in terms of outputting, we have only covered alert(); and return(); functions. right now they are the only two methods to relay information

Comment: `return` is neither a function nor an output method. Luckily, `JSON.stringify` isn't either, it only transforms an object to a string, which means you can use it - the output is still done by `alert`.

Comment: @DavidSherret is that the same as alert(String(urlScores(web, 'uni'))); ?

Comment: @air6199 no it's different. That's basically the exact same thing as calling `alert(urlScores(web, 'uni'));` Why not try it out for yourself to see? Open up the web browser console and type in `String({ test: "my test" });` and hit enter. Then type in `JSON.stringify({ test: "my test" });` and hit enter. See what happens. You should also do some reading on [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: @DavidSherret yep was just doing that. it makes sense now but the problem i have is that this technique is not on the criteria for our coursework. we were strictly told to not use any new methods :/ is there an alternative to this at all?

Comment: @air6199 I would suggest reading up on [debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging). You can set breakpoints to pause the execution of your script and then inspect what's in variables. It will help you a lot now and with your future coursework. You'll be ahead of the game. (It might not be in your coursework, but you don't write any code to do it. I would be extremely surprised if an instructor was angry that you were debugging code)

Comment: @air6199 basically, set a breakpoint on the `return(results);` line and see what's in the `results` variable when the code hits that line. You might need to set a breakpoint and then refresh the page for the code to run.

Comment: @DavidSherret will do, thanks for the heads up. i think i'll have to use this JSON method and add a note in my description sheet as to why i had to to it this way. Thanks stackoverflow and members. i'll be back.